# CharacterController.move strange behavior

Tags: unity-game-engine, accelerometer, unityscript

HI I have a question regarding charactercontroller.Move() function when I use the following code to turn character left ,right ,forward & back it works fine

```
function Update () {
  var controller : CharacterController = GetComponent(CharacterController);
    if (controller.isGrounded) {
        // We are grounded, so recalculate
        // move direction directly from axes
         accel = Vector3.Lerp(accel, Input.acceleration, 5.0f* Time.deltaTime);
        moveDirection = Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0,
                                Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection *= speed;

        if (Input.GetButton ("Jump")) {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
    }
    // Apply gravity
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    // Move the controller
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

for example when i move it left from current position to 0.35f it moves to 0.35f and stops there.but when I try to move the player by accelerometer it doesn't works the same way I am just modifying one line in the above code to this :

```
function Update () {

  var controller : CharacterController = GetComponent(CharacterController);
    if (controller.isGrounded) {
        // We are grounded, so recalculate
        // move direction directly from axes
         accel = Vector3.Lerp(accel, Input.acceleration, 5.0f* Time.deltaTime);
         inputX=accel.x;
        print(inputX);
        moveDirection = Vector3(inputX, 0,
                                Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection *= speed;

        if (Input.GetButton ("Jump")) {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
    }
    // Apply gravity
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    // Move the controller
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I also noted that log of inputX remain almost constant when i don't move my device but still the x value of the controller keep on changing and increasing.Can anyone explain what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to remap the input according to the device rotation. The help page on the acceleration input (http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input-acceleration.html) shows how to remap the incoming data to your game environment.

Comment: Thanks for reply but it is not with remapping the input inputs are mapped like i tilt device right it moves right snd vice versa its just that my player keeps on moving right even if i keep the device static . I tried the above code as well it has the same problem that value coming from the accelerometer changes the player x and z position even if I had kept the device static

Comment: Could you print out the raw values from the accelerometer (before doing any calculations with them) to see if they actually correspond to your input. If they do, then at least you know that the issue is with the calculations.